# Very non-linear audio amplifier behaviour: how to diagnose?

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm trying to build an audio amplifier based on the [ESP 3a](https://sound-au.com/project3a.htm) design:

[image]

I'm currently at the stage where it is actually doing some amplification, but somehow the low frequency response is very bad, and I'm kinda stumped where to look for the actual issue. I plotted the frequency response from 20Hz all the way up to 100kHz:

[image]

I'm at a loss to understand what is going on here. I would have expected any issues due to bad layout/bad components to arise in the high frequency part of the response, but that's the only part where it seems linear!

The response looks like there is some kind of high-pass filter in place. It's not the DC blocking capacitor C1 on the input, that one tests fine. One deviation I have is D1, the voltage there is on the low side (it's a red LED), but that should not cause this kind of problems, I believe?

Comment: Post a schematic please.

Comment: The schematic is linked, I'm not sure if I can hotlink the image from that website? But, let me try. Edit: appears to be working :)

Comment: What is the load on the output during the test?

Comment: An 8 ohm power resistor

Comment: Check that C3 is really 100 microfarads. Your plot makes me think C3 is 100 nF. Next time, plot dB gain. Much easier for many of us to understand. Since you say it is non-linear, is the waveform distorted or just low in amplitude at lower frequencies?

Comment: @qrk it's a 100u electrolytic, i double-checked. The only difference I see is that I managed to reverse the polarity, the negative is connected to gnd on my pcb. Looking at the schematic it shouldn't matter much, I believe there's low-voltage audio on this capacitor?

Comment: @qrk I'll try to add a dB gain plot. I thought that making both axes log it would more or less the same? And as for the waveform, there's no distortion at all, I get a clean-looking sine wave output. I did some measuring as well, distortion seems to be low, but the measurement setup was not such that I want to call this a conclusive result :D

Comment: Ok that was indeed the issue, the capacitor stopped capacitating :') it was around 85nF. It was probably another casualty from an earlier "magic smoke" incident I had. For good measure I also replaced the red LED with a green one as @user107063 suggested below. but I think C3 was the main culprit. If you want, you can add it as an answer and then I can accept it. Thanks for helping out a beginner!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that C3 is really 100 microfarads. Your plot makes me think C3 is 100 nF. I'm a little worried that a polarized capacitor is used. Bipolar electrolytics are available, or use a ceramic capacitor (need to understand how the part behaves in your circuit due to capacitance being a function of voltage across the capacitor).

dB gain for most of us is easier to interpret. Also, as done, log frequency axis is easier to interpret.

Comment: As mentioned, this was the biggest issue, I don't know how much the red LED contributed, but I changed that as well. Regarding the voltage: looking at the circuit, my limited understanding is that the voltage over C3 can not be higher than the voltage at the base of Q2, which should be the same as that on the base of Q1, which is half that of line level audio due to R1 + R3, so at most 1.736/2=0.868V, which should not pose a problem for a polarized electrolytic I think?

Answer (score 3):

Using a red LED for D1 is a bad idea since it drastically reduces the current sink into Q3.  The voltage across R6 cannot exceed the voltage across R7, and the voltage across R7 is 0.65V less than the voltage across D1 already.  But the voltage across R6 has to exceed 0.65V in order to drive Q4.  Since Q4 is effectively dead, the sole current that remains for driving your Q5/Q7 Sziklai pair is what manages to pass through C4.

So either get a green LED for D1, or put a normal silicon diode in series with your red one.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the kind of insight/knowledge I was hoping for!! I do have green leds available, but they have a forward voltage of 2.65V, and the red ones i have are 1.94V. That felt closer to the desired value, but it is indeed causing the issue you described. Voltage over D1 is 1.94V, over R6 is 0.61V, which is not enough.

Will the slightly too high forward voltage drop over the green LED I have cause an issue? Your suggestion of an extra diode in series would suggest not :)

And, another question, why not use a 2V2 zener instead?

Comment: @Michel At equilibrium, the current sunk into Q3 will get distributed more or less half and half through Q1 and Q2.  That's not an absolute requirement since C3 will accumulate any DC offset at the output and compensate for it, but you mostly want equilibrium with equal currents also to keep temperatures uniform for both Q1/Q2 (you should also thermically join them, letting them share a sink or place their cases touching).  So since you want the current across R6 to be roughly half of the one across R7, you want something like 1.3V across R7 for best thermal stability.